# Who were the nine actors who played the nine kings?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, movie, tolkiens-legendarium

One of the things I liked about the production of the Lord of the Rings films was that some crew members were invited to play a sort of *cameo* role. Unfortunately, some members do not get credited for their **brief** performance (although I seemed to remember reading somewhere that some crew members had requested to be uncredited).

**Regardless, I was wondering if anyone knew the names of those who played the nine Kings from an early scene from *The Fellowship of the Ring*?**

I could only find two crew members:

- **Red circle** - [John Howe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Howe_%28illustrator%29)
- **Blue circle** - [Alan Lee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Lee_%28illustrator%29)

[image: Nine Kings to rule them all]

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Alan Lee and John Howe aren't just crew members, they are also famous illustrators of Tolkien's works.

Comment: Hmm IMDB shows there were 12 actors who played the Ringwraiths - interesting!

Comment: @N_Soong May have been different actors for the fight scenes versus the riding scenes

Comment: @JasonBaker Indeed, but it doesn't help ups much does it!

Comment: @WadCheber - Thanks Wad, I was aware they were quite famous beforehand but didn't realise they made a lot of illustrations!

Comment: @N_Soong - Cheers buddy, you certainly picked up a very interesting fact! But you're right, shame it doesn't help in terms of naming the people involved :)

Comment: @user35594 - Tolkien Gateway entries for [John Howe](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/John_Howe) and [Alan Lee](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Alan_Lee)

Comment: @WadCheber - Many thanks for the very helpful links!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In addition to Lee and Howe (who, being relatively famous in the Tolkien community, dominate the conversation), all I've been able to find is that Brent McIntyre, who is credited with the role of the Witch-king, almost certainly played him in the prologue.

Here's McIntyre:

[image: Brent McIntyre]

Here's the Witch-king in Wraith-form makeup (signed by McIntyre, no less):

[image: The Witch-king]

And here's the central face from the OP's picture:

[image: The not-Witch-king]

Comment: "Congratulations! You're the winner!"

Comment: According to http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Witch-king it was an "An unidentified extra" and not Brent McIntyre who is mentioned as playing the Witch King separately.

Comment: @chx Interesting, but I'd find it more compelling if it had a source; I'll go hunting for one, but if you find one first don't hesitate to post it

Comment: I don't think they aged him up, I think that's a different person.

Answer (score 12):

I don't know if you're still curious, but the first one on the left next to the Witch King was my granddad (in effect) Garth Coppet. He died about 7 years ago. I would guess that most of these guys are just from random newpaper classifieds across New Zealand. That's how he got the gig. He didn't like photos, so I dont have any photos of him before he died, so I'm glad I at least have this.

Answer (score 11):

The one to the far right is my father, Graham Viskovic, who passed away a few years ago. Not an actor, just a New Zealander who did some extra work sometimes and had the right "look". He told us that each of the rings was real, unique and with the proper script on the inside (and no, he didn't get to keep it).

Comment: Do you have a source for this, or another image of him that you could post?

Answer (score 7):

My dad, Graham Johnson, is the third from the right. He is a local poet and was pulled off the street in Wellington by the casting director.

I still pause on this moment to give dad his 15 minutes of fame!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  It's neat to get more names filled in after all this time.  Do you have a comparative photo like some of the other answers, so we can put a face to the name?

Answer (score -1):

Although Brent McIntyre portrays the witch-king in wraight-form and is the only one credited for the role, I'm pretty sure it's actor Michael Elsworth, who portrays the witch-king in human form during the prologue. For a matter of fact, he also portrays Círdan in 'The Return of the King'. Despite the fact that he is in no way credited for the part, the similarities seem clear and obvious to me.

[image: Michael Elsworth]

Comment: That link doesn't credit him as the King.

Comment: @User1783 - Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by [edit]ing it to include images of the character and the actor for comparative purposes.